# How would I access a function inside of an angular module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Snippet of code

```
angular.module("app.wallet", ["app.wallet.directive", "app.wallet.service"]),
angular.module("app.wallet.service", []).factory("$wallet", ["$rootScope", "$$http", "$e", "$toast", "errorMap", "$popup", "$google", function(t, e, n, a, r, o, i) {
    var s = {};
    return s.withdraw = function(t) {
        var n = e.link({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/btc/withdraw",
            data: {
                amount: t.amount,
                address: t.btcAddress
            },
            success: Do stuff
            failure: Do other stuff
        });
        n.req()
    }
    ,
    s
}
]),
```

Specifically I need to be able to call the withdraw function from chromes console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `angular.injector`

```
angular.injector(['app.wallet']).get('$wallet').withdraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just attach anything to window by writing `window.saved = s` for example.

Then from your debug console, if the code as been executed before, you will have `saved` available:

```
angular.module("app.wallet", ["app.wallet.directive", "app.wallet.service"]),
angular.module("app.wallet.service", []).factory("$wallet", ["$rootScope", "$$http", "$e", "$toast", "errorMap", "$popup", "$google", function(t, e, n, a, r, o, i) {
    var s = {};
    s.withdraw = function(t) {
        var n = e.link({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/btc/withdraw",
            data: {
                amount: t.amount,
                address: t.btcAddress
            },
            success: Do stuff
            failure: Do other stuff
        });
        n.req()
    }
    window.saved = s;
    console.log('you can now acces withdraw by typing saved.withdraw in your console');
    return s;
}
]),
```